# How to change directory to the old directory?

Tags: command-line

I am currently in /downloads directory. Before I was in /var/www directory. How can I return back to the old directory in terminal? I do not want to execute  `cd /var/www`

I need a simple command to change to old directory.

Answer (score 1):

with bash you can use `cd -` to go to the old directory also known as `$OLDPWD`

Answer (score 1):

`cd -` : return back to old directory

example:

```
pwd
```

gives

```
/home/julia/Downloads
```

Now

```
cd -
```

then

```
pwd
```

gives

```
/var/www
```

`cd ..` : return back to parent directory

`cd ~`: go to home directory